# add row data from child window to parent window table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup modal where I enter info. On saving I want to add the data as a `row` to a table of the `opener` or parent window.

The code bellow works fine in any browser accept IE11, EDGE and probably the IE predecessors.

```
$('#OPER > tbody:last', window.opener.document).one().append(tr);
```

Is there a possible JQuery way to do so.

As there is only one `#OPER` I was thinking

```
$('#OPER tbody').append(tr);
```

or

```
$('#OPER').find('tbody').append( tr );
```

but Im not sure it will sent it to the parent where the `#OPER` table is located.

Comment: `$(window.opener.document).find('#OPER').children('tbody').last().append(tr);` this should work. IE tends to have issues with `:last` or `>` selectors I guess.

Comment: Or this is the issue you are having. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625733/how-do-i-get-around-window-opener-cross-domain-security