# OAuth popup cross-domain security React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, popup, authorization

I'm interested in how to implement OAuth in React using popup (`window.open`).

For example I have:

1. `mysite.com` — this is where I open the popup.
2. `passport.mysite.com/oauth/authorize` — popup.

The main question is how to create connection between `window.open` (popup) and `window.opener` (as it's known the window.opener is null due to cross-domain security therefore we can't use it anymore).

> ⇑ `window.opener` is removed whenever you navigate to a different host (for security reasons), there is no way around it. The only option should be doing the payment in a frame if it is possible. The top document needs to stay on the same host.

**Scheme:**

[image]

**Possible solutions:**

1. Check an opened window using `setInterval` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712160/9464680).
2. <s>Using [cross-storage](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage) (not worth it imho ).</s>

---

So what's the best recommended approach in 2019?

> Wrapper for React - https://github.com/Ramshackle-Jamathon/react-oauth-popup

Comment: In 2019, localStorage support is much better. I would go with localStorage approach (described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625733/how-do-i-get-around-window-opener-cross-domain-security/18712160#18712160) as it does not seem like much a workaround. The parent window does not need to periodically check for the child window status.`setInterval` could be used as fallback for localStorage

Comment: @KhanhTO, yeah, I completely agree with you about `localStorage`, but it only works for the same domain so it doesn't work in my condition

Comment: After you finish with OAuth, the child window is redirected back to your domain, you are in the same domain now with the parent

Comment: @KhanhTO, hm, this is great idea! I should have known..

Comment: It would be even better if the browser restores `window.opener` after redirecting back to our domain, but this is not the case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suggested by [Khanh TO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1957251/khanh-to). OAuth popup with localStorage. Based on [react-oauth-popup](https://github.com/Ramshackle-Jamathon/react-oauth-popup).

**Scheme:**

[image]

**Code:**

**`oauth-popup.tsx:`**

```
import React, {PureComponent, ReactChild} from 'react'

type Props = {
  width: number,
  height: number,
  url: string,
  title: string,
  onClose: () => any,
  onCode: (params: any) => any,
  children?: ReactChild,
}

export default class OauthPopup extends PureComponent<Props> {

  static defaultProps = {
    onClose: () => {},
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    url: "",
    title: ""
  };

  externalWindow: any;
  codeCheck: any;

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.externalWindow) {
      this.externalWindow.close();
    }
  }

  createPopup = () => {
    const {url, title, width, height, onCode} = this.props;
    const left = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth - width) / 2;
    const top = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight - height) / 2.5;

    const windowFeatures = `toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=0,location=1,menuBar=0,width=${width},height=${height},top=${top},left=${left}`;

    this.externalWindow = window.open(
        url,
        title,
        windowFeatures
    );

    const storageListener = () => {
      try {
        if (localStorage.getItem('code')) {
          onCode(localStorage.getItem('code'));
          this.externalWindow.close();
          window.removeEventListener('storage', storageListener);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        window.removeEventListener('storage', storageListener);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', storageListener);

    this.externalWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      this.props.onClose()
    }, false);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.createPopup)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**`app.tsx`**

```
import React, {FC} from 'react'

const onCode = async (): Promise<undefined> => {
  try {
    const res = await <your_fetch>
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('code'); //remove code from localStorage
  }
}

const App: FC = () => (
  <OAuthPopup
    url={<your_url>}
    onCode={onCode}
    onClose={() => console.log('closed')}
    title="<your_title>">
    <button type="button">Enter</button>
  </OAuthPopup>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

I once encounter an issue on my oauth login flow with [window.open/window.opener bug on ms-edge](https://forums.asp.net/t/2150138.aspx)

My flow before this issue was

- On login button click open a popup
- After successful login the oauth app redirect to my domain's page
- Then i call a function of the parent window from with in the popup (window.opener.fn) with data from oauth response and the parent window then close the child popup window

My flow after this issue was

- On login button click open a popup
- Create a setinterval in case (window.opener is undefined)
- After successful login the oauth app redirect to my domain's page
- Check if window.opener is available then do #3 from the above flow and clearInterval
- If window.opener is not available then since i am on my domains page i try to set localstorage and try to read the localstorage from inside the setInterval function in parent window then clear the localstorage and setInterval and proceed.
- (for backward compatibility) If localstorage is also not available then  set a client side cookie with the data with a short expiry (5-10 sec) time and try to read the cookie (document.cookie) inside the setInterval function in parent window and proceed.