# IE shows window.closed as true even if the window is Open

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I followed the example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18804255/2601664) to load a external third party url in a child window. The issue that I am facing is that in IE  `if (child.closed)` is true when child window is in a different domain. Is there any workaround for this behavior of IE?

The answer says that this the code was verified in IE10, I am using IE11. Not sure if this was changed in the later versions of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my IE browser security settings to make this work i.e. un-check the highlighted flag as shown below [image: attached]

My website was running with localhost domain name and the security policies that were being applied to it were the ones meant for intranet zone. I believe the security policies of intranet zone are relatively strict when compared to internet zone.